Change * to U00D7 multiplication symbol (×) in MATLAB with code
I am using MATLAB's fitlm function to analyse some test data, and then plotting the "raw output" as per the documentation. (matlab fitlm doc)
This plot(mdl) has an automatically generated legend, which has the equation of the linear model model in it, in the form:
y = m*x+c

I need to change this asterisk (*) to the multiplication symbol, U00D7, (×), such that:
y = m × x+c

Is it possible to do this with code or do I need to change it manually?
clear
clc

%Make test data
%----------------------------
x1 = 1:0.01:3;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
x1 = x1 + r;

y1 = 1:0.01:3;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
y1 = y1 + r;

x1 = x1';
y1 = y1';
label1 = zeros(length(y1),1);

Tclust1 = [label1,x1,y1];
%----------------------------
x2 = 4:0.01:6;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
x2 = x2 + r;

y2 = 10:0.01:12;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
y2 = y2 + r;

x2 = x2';
y2 = y2';
label2 = ones(length(y2),1);

Tclust2 = [label2,x2,y2];

%----------------------------
x3 = 5:0.01:7;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
x3 = x3 + r;

y3 = 11:0.01:13;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
y3 = y3 + r;

x3 = x3';
y3 = y3';
label3 = label2+1;

Tclust3 = [label3,x3,y3];
%----------------------------
T = [Tclust1;Tclust2;Tclust3];

%Prep for LM -------------------------------------------------------------
%Classify by labels
Label_idx = zeros(length(T(:,1)),1);

for qq = 1:length(Label_idx)  
    if T(qq,1) > 0
        Label_idx(qq) = 1;
    end
end

for qq = 1:length(Label_idx)
    if T(qq,1) > 1
        Label_idx(qq) = 2;
    end
end

%dummy variables
for qq = 1:length(Label_idx)
    if Label_idx(qq) == 0
        Label_1(qq) = 1;
    else
    Label_1(qq) = 0;
    end
end

Label_1 = Label_1';

for qq = 1:length(Label_idx)
    if Label_idx(qq) == 2
        Label_2(qq) = 1;
    else
    Label_2(qq) = 0;
    end
end

Label_2 = Label_2';

%Do the Linear modelling -------------------------------------------------

%Input predictor
pred = (T(:,2));
%Input comparator
comp = (T(:,3));

%interaction parameters
int_lo = pred.*Label_1;
int_hi = pred.*Label_2;

%predictors
    X = [pred,Label_1,Label_2,int_lo,int_hi];
    LR_mdl = fitlm(X,comp);

%plot ==========================================================
plot(LR_mdl)

    
    

        
        


This will do the job:
h = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'legend'); % get the legend object in the current figure
h.String = strrep(h.String, '*', char(hex2dec('D7'))); % replace in all strings

Or, with spaces around the multiplication symbol:
h.String = strrep(h.String, '*', [' ' char(hex2dec('D7')) ' ']);


You can modify the DisplayName property of the line objects in the current figure. Using arrayfun to loop over the lines and findall to get a handle on those lines, this becomes:
arrayfun( @(x) set(x,'DisplayName',strrep(x.DisplayName,'*','×')), findall(gcf,'type','line') )

Since this is an automatic legend, it will update to reflect the lines' display names.

Nice approach, I keep forgetting about DisplayName
